# Column height in bootstrap 4 grid system with row-cols

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In the below code i have a bootstrap grid system utilizing attribute row-col. My problem is when columns wrap they do not keep the height of the largest columns from previous "rows". Any way to have the columns that wrap keep the height of the other largest col?

Trying to figure out if there is an intelligent way to achieve this within bootstraps frame, trivial solutions like "min-height" are not acceptable.

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-4" id="cordContainer">
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100 border-primary">
                <div class="card-header bg-primary"></div>
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i0.wp.com/www.impact-media.be/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/placeholder-1-e1533569576673-960x960.png">
                <div class="card-body border-top p-2"><p class="card-text text-center">Test</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100 border-primary">
                <div class="card-header bg-primary"></div>
                <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.nebero.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder.jpg">
                <div class="card-body border-top p-2"><p class="card-text text-center">Test</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100 border-primary">
                <div class="card-header bg-primary"></div>
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x640.png">
                <div class="card-body border-top p-2"><p class="card-text text-center">Test</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100 border-primary">
                <div class="card-header bg-primary"></div>
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x640.png">
                <div class="card-body border-top p-2"><p class="card-text text-center">Test</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100 border-primary">
                <div class="card-header bg-primary"></div>
                <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.nebero.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder.jpg">
                <div class="card-body border-top p-2"><p class="card-text text-center">Test</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-cols-1" id="otherItemsContainer">
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ak7nb9mx/

Answer (score 0):

If JS is an option:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var maxVal = 0;
    document.querySelectorAll('#cordContainer > .col').forEach(function(value, index) {
        if (parseInt(value.offsetHeight) > maxVal) maxVal = parseInt(value.offsetHeight);
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('#cordContainer > .col').forEach(function(value, index) {
        value.style.height = maxVal + "px";
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a purely CSS solution, Thank you for the input though.